# write vs fprintf - why different and which is better?

Tags: c, pthreads, printf

I have recently started learning the wonders of pthreads according to POSIX 1003.1c.

PThreads may seem complex, but they are basically simple threads that we use in the class to create parallel behavior: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

As I am still learning, my teacher gave us a C code to toy with:

```
/* Creates two threads, one printing 10000 "a"s, the other printing
   10000 "b"s.
   Illustrates: thread creation, thread joining. */

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "pthread.h"

void * process(void * arg)
{
  int i;
  fprintf(stderr, "Starting process %s\n", (char *) arg);
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       write(1, (char *) arg, 1);
//      fprintf(stdout, (char *) arg, 1);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  int retcode;
  pthread_t th_a, th_b;
  void * retval;

  retcode = pthread_create(&th_a, NULL, process, "a");
  if (retcode != 0) fprintf(stderr, "create a failed %d\n", retcode);

  retcode = pthread_create(&th_b, NULL, process, "b");
  if (retcode != 0) fprintf(stderr, "create b failed %d\n", retcode);

  retcode = pthread_join(th_a, &retval);
  if (retcode != 0) fprintf(stderr, "join a failed %d\n", retcode);

  retcode = pthread_join(th_b, &retval);
  if (retcode != 0) fprintf(stderr, "join b failed %d\n", retcode);

  return 0;
}
```

  Instructions to run and compile (for linux):
- Run command: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
- Donwload this code (obviously xD)
- Use the following command to compile: `gcc -D_REENTRANT filenName.c -lpthread`
- Run the result by using the command: `./a.out`

Everything works but I don't understand why my output order is different depending on the use of `write` or `fprintf`.

When I use `write` I get a random output of letters like the following:

```
Starting process a
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaStarting process b
aaababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

But when I use `fprintf` I always get the get an output similar to:

```
Starting process a
Starting process b
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaababbabaabaabaababbabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

In this case, the text "Starting process" always appears first and is not mixed with the rest of the output. Why is this happening? Is it because `write` is very fast and `fprintf` is slower?

As a C programmer, which one should I use and why?

Comment: The commented out `fprintf()` line seems to be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`write` is a system call: it sends the given characters directly to the operating system, which (in theory, and often in practice) sends them immediately to the output device such as the screen or disk.

`fprintf` (and `fwrite` and anything that takes a `FILE *` argument) is a library call, which buffers, or collects, the data inside your program before sending it. This allows it to send larger, more uniform chunks of data, which improves efficiency.

What you see with `write` is that each call causes a thread switch as the program waits for the operating system to confirm whether the write succeeded. When one thread is waiting, the other thread gets time.

With `fprintf`, it never does anything so exceptional. It's actually just one thread filling an array with `a`'s until it's done. The operating system is none the wiser until it receives the filled buffer (via `write`). Then since the first thread has no more work, it runs the second. If you printed more characters, you would see `fprintf` also interleave `a`'s and `b`'s as the chunks get sent to the operating system.

As for "fast" and "slow", `write` is more immediate in sending its output, but `fprintf` is faster in pretty much every other way and is the general correct choice (or `fwrite` which is more similar to `write`).

Comment: +1 - as an addition: `write` and `fwrite` are designed for writing binary data instead of strings. `fprintf` is for strings.

Answer (score 3):

Write wraps a kernel call, and it's not buffered. It just copies n bytes from the buffer to the file descriptor.

fprintf is buffered and also it is meant to do string processing and replace the various %d, %s with the parameters, so it is much more complex to execute for this reason, having to parse the string that it receives.